# Reference a chapter as "first chapter" instead of "chapter 1"

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a report with several chapters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, notitlepage]{report}

\chapter{Title of chapter 1}
\label{chap:1}

\chapter{Title of chapter 2}
\label{chap:2}
```

Now what I want is to be able to reference to each chapter using something similar to `\ref{chap:1}` but instead of giving me the chapter number I want it converted to "first", "second", etc.

Something along the lines of:

```
In the \ref{chap:1} chapter, I show that (...)
```

Which would become:

```
In the first chapter, I show that (...)
```

Comment: Probably :). Let me give that a go! Thanks!